# DTE2.Documents Exception in VSIX CommandPackage

Tags: visual-studio-2015, vsix

I tried to do:

```
  Private _applicationObject As EnvDTE80.DTE2 = DirectCast(Me.ServiceProvider.GetService(GetType(SDTE)), DTE2)
  Dim docs As EnvDTE.Documents = _applicationObject.Documents
  Dim doc As EnvDTE.Document
  For Each doc In docs
  'foobar()
  Next
```

But in Line 4 at the "docs" there's a unknown COM-Exception. The Header/Extension of the calling Class:

```
<PackageRegistration(UseManagedResourcesOnly:=True)>
<InstalledProductRegistration("#3110", "#3112", "1.0", IconResourceID:=3400)>
<ProvideMenuResource("Menus.ctmenu", 1)>
<Guid(Command1Package.PackageGuidString)>
<ProvideAutoLoad(UIContextGuids80.SolutionExists)>
Public NotInheritable Class Command1Package
   Inherits Package
```

In the Command Class I extend the contextmenu on the document tabs. Whats the problem there? Well I found a solution, but want to understand the problem here.
Instead of Documents I have to use Windows and filter for kind = "Document".

Any Idea?

Exception:

```
System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException ist aufgetreten.
  ErrorCode=-2147467259
  HResult=-2147467259
  Message=Unbekannter Fehler (Ausnahme von HRESULT: 0x80004005 (E_FAIL))
  Source=""
  StackTrace:
       bei System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHRInternal(Int32 errorCode, IntPtr errorInfo)
       bei Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Design.Serialization.DesignerDocDataService.Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.IVsRunningDocTableEvents.OnBeforeLastDocumentUnlock(UInt32 docCookie, UInt32 lockType, UInt32 readLocksRemaining, UInt32 editLocksRemaining)
       bei EnvDTE.Documents.GetEnumerator()
       bei TabContextMenuExt.Command1.CloseAllWorkingDocuments() in C:\_demos\jur\TabContextMenuExt\Command1.vb:Zeile 84.
  InnerException:
```